# I cant save the animation

Tags: python, animation, ffmpeg, mp4

i tried various examples though i cant find proper solution. This is the example code of my project i want to save this in a mp4 format and i used ffmpeg. Any suggestion for this would be appreciated. Thank you in advance

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import ma``tplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

df = data.iloc[0:250, 4:12]
df1 = df2.iloc[:,0:3]

a1 = df.iloc[:,0]/2
a2 = df.iloc[:,1]/2
b1 = df.iloc[:,2]/2
b2 = df.iloc[:,3]/2
c1 = df.iloc[:,4]/2
c2 = df.iloc[:,5]/2
m1 = df1.iloc[:,0]
m2 = df1.iloc[:,1]
m3 = df1.iloc[:,2]

fig ,ax = plt.subplots()

l1, = ax.plot (vert1, vert2, 'ro', markersize = m1[0])
l2, = ax.plot (long1, long2, 'ro', markersize = m2[0])
l3, = ax.plot (tras1, tras2, 'ro', markersize = m3[0])

def init():    
    l1.set_data([],[])
    l2.set_data([],[])
    l3.set_data([],[])
    
    return (l1,l2,l3)

def animate(i,l1,l2,l3):
    
    l1.set_data(vert1[i], vert2[i])
    l1.set_markersize(m1[i])
    l2.set_data(long1[i], long2[i])
    l2.set_markersize(m2[i])
    l3.set_data(tras1[i], tras2[i])
    l3.set_markersize(m3[i])

    return (l1,l2,l3)

Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
writer = Writer(fps= 100, metadata = dict(artist = 'me'), bitrate = 1800)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs=(l1,l2,l3), init_func=init, interval=10, blit=False)
ani.save('/Users/gokulthangavel/Downloads/basic_animation.mp4', writer = writer)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you please post a code sample we can execute? In case you can't post the data, be creative and replace it with simple data samples.

Comment: df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(2,8,[250,3]))

Comment: sorry I cant make samples on df  its time series data and its a tracking data of a person in laser game.

Comment: I posted an answer (I hope it helps - your code looks correct). Can you be more specific about the problem you are having. No error message? `basic_animation.mp4` file is created or not? Does the program finish executing or get stuck? Do you get an empty figure or something else?

Answer (score 0):

The code looks correct.

I tried to reproduce the problem with synthetic data (`sin` and `cos`) - replacing the data you didn't post.

I modified some of the arguments:

- Reduce the fps from `fps=100` to `fps=10` (100 fps is too fast).
- Add an argument `frames=200` for creating animation with 200 frames.

If I have to guess, your problem is related to the input data (unposted data).
It could be that the data points exceeds the axes limit, and all the data points are outside the axis (or other issues of that kind).

It is also possible that the interval is too large or that the animation is too long.

---

According to the documentation, it looks like you need to return the axes:

```
return ax
```

But `return (l1, l2, l3)` works (the returned value is ignored).

---

Here is a modified version of your code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig ,ax = plt.subplots()

fig.set_size_inches(4, 3)  # Reduce size of Stack Overflow posting.

l1, = ax.plot (np.arange(1, 10), np.arange(1, 10), **{'marker':'o'})
l2, = ax.plot (np.arange(1, 10), np.arange(1, 10), **{'marker':'o'})
l3, = ax.plot (np.arange(1, 10), np.arange(1, 10), **{'marker':'o'})

def init():
    l1.set_data([],[])
    l2.set_data([],[])
    l3.set_data([],[])
    
    return (l1, l2, l3)

def animate(i, l1, l2, l3):
    l1.set_data(i/22, np.sin(0.1*i)*4+5)
    l1.set_markersize(4)
    l2.set_data(i/22, np.cos(0.01*i*i)*4+5)
    l2.set_markersize(5)
    l3.set_data(9-i/22, (-np.cos(0.1*i))*4+5)
    l3.set_markersize(6)
 
    # return ax
    return (l1, l2, l3)

Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
writer = Writer(fps=10, metadata=dict(artist = 'me'), bitrate=1800)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs=(l1,l2,l3), init_func=init, frames=200, interval=1, blit=False)  # 200 frames, interval=1
#ani.save('basic_animation.mp4', writer=writer)
ani.save('basic_animation.gif', writer=writer)  # Create animated gif (instead of mp4) for Stack Overflow posting.

plt.show()
```

---

Result:
[image: animation]

Comment: Thank you so much but it didn't work actually it shows no error (keyerror = 0) and also the file gets saved but its not playing.

Comment: Did you try to execute the code from my post? Replace the file name to `'/Users/gokulthangavel/Downloads/basic_animation.mp4'`. If it's not working, try `basic_animation.gif`. File that get saved but not playing, could be that the program never ends, and file is not closed properly. It might be player issue. Try playing with VLC, or update the video codecs (install K-Lite codec pack).

Comment: I tried your code it saved and played well there is no problem in yours in execution

Comment: I cant even see the animation when I run the ani.save line, if I am not run the ani.save line then the animation works.

Comment: I thin you are right, the program wasn't ends may be the file not closed properly. i used df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(250,8)) this data instead of df then it saved and played well.